# Expectation of a random variable over disjoint intervals

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I wanted to know if there is a formal way to show the following.
Say I have a random variable `X` that takes value over the interval `[-1, 1]`.

Now I split the interval in 2 parts `A = [-1, 0]` and `B = [0, 1]`
Intuitively I think I can write the expected value of `X` as:

`E[X] = E[X|X in A] + E[X|X in B]` by summing the conditional expectation on the two disjoint sets.

I am struggling to get a formal proof.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your idea is right but you need to "weight" each conditional expectation by the associated probability.

For a variable $X$ and an event $E$, the conditional expectation $\mathbb E(X\mid E)$ is defined as ($I$ is the indicator function),
$$
\mathbb E(X \mid E) = \frac{\mathbb E(XI_E)}{\mathbb P(E)}
$$
which gives
$$
\mathbb E(XI_E) = \mathbb E(X \mid E) \mathbb P(E)
$$

In your case since $B= A^c$ we can write the variable $X$ as

$$
X = XI_{X\in A} + XI_{X\in B}
$$

By linearity of the expectation we have
$$
\mathbb E(X) = \mathbb E(XI_{X\in A}) + \mathbb E (XI_{X\in B})
$$
where
$$
\mathbb E(X I_{X \in A}) = \mathbb E(X\mid X\in A)\mathbb P(X \in A)
$$
and
$$
\mathbb E(X I_{X \in B}) = \mathbb E(X\mid X\in B)\mathbb P(X \in B)
$$
Therefore the expectation of $X$ is
$$
\mathbb E(X) = \mathbb E(X\mid X\in A)\mathbb P(X \in A) + \mathbb E(X\mid X\in B)\mathbb P(X \in B)
$$

Comment: super clear. thank you!